# Size of outputs in OpenMDAO

Tags: arrays, variables, matrix, openmdao

Is it possible to have lists or arrays passed as outputs of components in openMDAO?

Since my problem relies on 6x6 matrices to solve an equation of motion in 6 degrees of freedom, I would like to be able to do the following:

```
M = np.ones([6, 6])
outputs['M'] = M
```

However, that results in an error:

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 36 into shape (1,)

Is there any way to avoid passing each of 36 values seperately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can declare an output of any size or shape in your component's `setup` method by doing the following:

```
self.add_output('M', shape=(6, 6))
```

or

```
self.add_output('M', val=np.ones((6, 6)))
```